# docker-compose ssh

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Estoy trabajando en crear un .Dockerfile un docker-compose.ymal y un archivo a.sh que contiene variables de entorno y un `tail -f /dev/null`.

Quiero crear dos contenedores que se comuniquen entre sí. Tiene que tener openssh  y git, volúmenes y puerto de comunicación. La idea es crear un entorno seguro de desarroyo. El arhivo a.sh tiene que contener variables de entorno de USER y de PASSWORD y ser recogido en el .Dockerfile.

Estoy muy perdido. Ojalá puedan ayudarme y reconozco que igual es algo confuso ya que yo mismo no tengo claro ni por donde tirar.

Comment: Va a ser complicado tio.... Bueno, mi consejo es que habras puertos y ataques a esos puertos... Vaya que "salgas por una puerta, para entrar en otra". No se muy bien como se hace eso por que nunca lo he echo, pero se que la comunicación P2P usando ssh o similares en docker funciona con **IPTables** algo que hasta docker dice que es jodido y funciona de culo... No se que decirte espero que tengas suerte

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/ te redirijo a la pagina que buscas

Comment: Yo intente hacer un WMare usando docker y me encontre con una infinidad de problemas, como... que IP's tienen los contenedores... que puertos estan expuestos... Yo creo que vas a tener problemas, incluso igual no puedes hacerlo

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia